# Vue navigate to next route after 10 seconds

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

I'm planning to make a infoscreen with Vue. At the moment I've two views.

The first view navigates to second view after 10 seconds and vica versa.

```
<template>
<div v-if="posts && posts.length">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Start</th>
            <th>Project</th>
            <th>Activity</th>
        </tr>
        <tr v-for="post of posts">
            <td>{{post.userName}}</td>
            <td>{{post.start}}</td>
            <td>{{post.projectName}}</td>
            <td>{{post.activityName}}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>

<div v-else-if="errors && errors.length">
    <h1>error connecting to API</h1>
</div>
```

```
<script>
    import axios from "axios";

    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                posts: [],
                errors: [],
                interval: null
            };
        },
        methods: {
            loadData() {
                axios
                    .get(
                        `http://myapi.com/infoscreen.php`
                    )
                    .then(response => {
                        this.posts = response.data;
                    })
                    .catch(e => {
                        this.errors.push(e);
                    });
            }
        },
        created() {
            this.loadData();
            this.interval = setInterval(
                function () {
                    this.$router.push({path: "/issues"});
                }.bind(this),
                10000
            );
        }
    };
</script>
```

The code works so far, after the 10 seconds a redirect to the route issues happens. Once the route issues is loaded after 10 seconds it navigates back to the page activity page from code example.

It seems like there is still the intervall set. Because now after 9.x seconds a redirect happens, and it goes faster and faster the more redirects happens until browser crashes.

So is there a best practise to do something like get all routes from router.js and then navigate to next page after 10 seconds?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Clear the interval when you redirect?

Comment: Clear the interval as @Li357 said or redirect with a setTimeout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two things. If you wish to use `setInterval` then clear the interval using `clearInterval`. Use `beforeDestroy` hook to do that.

Or better yet, use `setTimeout` instead of `setInterval`. With `setTimeout`, you won't have to clean up your timer. This is the recommended approach.